# How to extract values from a dataframe in Julia

Tags: dataframe, csv, datatables, julia

I would like to plot the energy per spin < E >/N against the temperature T. 
However, I am not sure how to "extract" the values from the table below and plot them.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do:

```
using Plots
plot(data.T, data.Emean)
```

This is the simplest way to get a column from a data frame.

You might also want to check out this notebook: https://github.com/bkamins/Julia-DataFrames-Tutorial/blob/master/02_basicinfo.ipynb in the section "
Most elementary get and set operations".